Why do you even need a heatshield - why not just cool the re-entry surfaces from inside?
Is it conceivable to instead of having a heatshield, to just have some sort of material or mechanism on the inside, that can convert the heat into something else?
A back of napkin calculation shows that a re-entering vehicle needs to get rid of about 3M joules of energy.
Eg. Phase change materials. You just fill the inside of the surface with salt, or silicon, and through some convection have it melt to the maxmimum temperature that you can safely confine, so as to keep the temperature on the outer surface under control. It seems that wouldn't need more than 20% of the mass of the spacecraft to make this work. Has this been tried?
Other ideas that spring to mind: Thermophotovolataics, Magentocalorics, Thermomechanicals.. charge batteries or manufacture something of value as you descend.

The Apollo CM's heat shield was on the order of 15% of the CM's mass. Throwing away the hot stuff for 15% of the mass instead of retaining the hot stuff for 20% seems like a win.

3 MJ sounds awfully low.

@Hobbes -- 3 MJ is just a tad low. My back of the napkin calculation is about 64 MJ per kg, assuming the vehicle hits the top of the atmosphere (120 km above the Earth's surface) at Earth escape velocity and lands (or splashes down) with near zero velocity at the Earth's surface. The vast majority of the energy is kinetic.

It seems to me this question is based on incorrect math, in which case it cannot be answered as it is @Dagelf.

0.83kWh of energy per kg?

This was considered at one stage of the Starship design. Specifically, cooling using cryogenic fuel. I believe one problem was that a single blockage in any cooling line would result in a catastrophic failure.

Whenever someone asks a question like this, the answer is always "engineers would have done that if were the best engineering solution".

Except the engineer of a certain submarine, I suppose?

The dry mass of a Dragon capsule is about 7,700 kg. Let's round that up to 8,000 kg because you have humans inside (that's a really lowball estimate because the start mass is about 12,000 kg with all the payload and propellants on board, but let's take that as a ballpark number).
In LEO the capsule has a speed of about 7,000 m/s. It will get rid of some of that speed with a deorbit burn but it will also trade altitude for speed so let's roll with that.
8,000 kg of mass at 7,000 m/s has an energy of 196 GJ. 196 GJ of energy to get rid of.
If use we water on board to store that heat in (water has a really high heat storage capacity), we can store about 400 kJ per kg of water when heating that from 0°C to 100°C. This means we would need a mere 490,000 kg of water to store that energy...
That seems a bit much. Let's say we let the water evaporate (one of the most energy intensive phase changes around). To evaporate 1 kg of water we need about 2 MJ. Add the heating from 0°C to 100°C to that and we're at a nice 2.4 MJ.
Than we're getting away with a mere 81,666 kg of water (for a 8,000 kg capsule)...
Even if we say, that 50% or even 90% of the heat is wicked away by the atmosphere, that's still an awfully big amount of energy to soak up.
Finding something that can "store" more energy per kg than water in a reasonable temperature range is not easy. That's why we insulate the capsule from the heatshield as good as it gets and let the heatshield get really freaking hot. Physics comes to the rescue because energy gets radiated away from an object at the 4th power of temperature. Doubling the temperature means that we can radiate 16 times the energy.

And the killer is that those 82 tons of water also start at orbital speed, carrying a whole lot of kinetic energy. Your 8 ton capsule just became a 90 ton one, so you need much more water to soak up all that energy. I guess you already see where this is going. It's the tyranny of the rocket equation all over again.

@TooTea Yo dwag I put some water to cool your water in your car ....err... capsule.

50% "wicked away by the atmosphere" is the minimum: you physically can't transfer more heat to the reentry vehicle than this.  For a blunt-body reentry vehicle, the percent transferred to the atmosphere is in the high 90s.  I can't find data for Crew Dragon, but for the missile reentry vehicles in the Allen and Eggers paper, 98% of the energy going to the atmosphere appears typical.  That brings the weight of water needed down to a level competitive with a heatshield.

Clearly, we simply need to build the capsule itself out of ice. ;)

@Mark true. But all those numbers are for heat shields that get really really hot... I interpreted the answer as looking for a way without a heatshield i.e. staying relatively cool.

@PM2Ring then it’s just an ablative heat shield

@fyrepenguin Sure. I was just being silly, hence the smilie.

PM2Ring - I wonder how big a block of ice would have to be in order to survive to ice cube size when it lands?

You don't need to get rid of all 196Gj in the upper atmosphere. No idea what the real percentage would be - no doubt it is a really complex calc.

(From a bit different perspective):
Storing heat is hard. It is one of the hardest things to do, in fact.
This doesn't mean that a "heat sink" type of reentry vehicle never makes sense. This type of design has been used in some early ballistic missile reentry vehicles, and works best with a very hot and fast reentry that leads to a lower total amount of heat. They lead to heavy designs and seem to mostly be used for suborbital vehicles where the heat load is less than for orbital or super-orbital ones.
In practice, storage and gradual cooling of heat that "soaks" through whatever heat shields are present is neccessary in many vehicles, except for those that simply jettison the heatshield or aeroshell after reentry.
Converting heat to something else is partially even harder and partially impossible.
The laws of thermodynamics dictate that it is impossible to convert more than a portion of incoming heat into any other form of energy, and to do this requires rejecting a large portion of the incoming heat, often more than 50%, at a lower temperature -- something that is somewhat hard to access in the fireball of atmospheric reentry. And you then have to deal with the fact that actually storing that energy is difficult -- there are very few ways to store energy that compete well with heating mass to a high temperature.

I believe there's a post-landing Shuttle emergency from a ground-support-truck cooling loop either not getting provided early enough or not working properly on the first try, but I can't find it anymore.

@ErinAnne you may be thinking of the ammonia boiler overcooling incident post landing on STS-27. Described herein https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20110003646/downloads/20110003646.pdf

Ah I think OrganicMarble is right about which one I was thinking of.  It still demonstrates some of the hideous difficulties of storing even relatively small amounts of heat (I think; it talks about the freon loops being used a cold-sink for entry while the radiators aren't available to cool the Shuttle from the heat production from the avionics/cabin/etc), reinforcing ikrase's first point. I think.
